# RecyclerView items not displaying

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, binding

The title says, I'm trying to load items into a recyclerview but the items doesn't displaying.

I'm getting the items from the api, using retrofit and mutablelivedata, I'm getting the items right, and the adapter gets the items (there are 3 items, and the adapter gets the 3 items), but the items doesn't display on the UI.

Here is my code:

**Adapter.java**

```
class EstablecimientosAdapter : ListAdapter<EstablecimientoModel, EstablecimientosViewHolder>(
    DIFF_CALLBACK
) {
    companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<EstablecimientoModel> =
            object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<EstablecimientoModel>() {
                override fun areItemsTheSame(
                    oldItem: EstablecimientoModel,
                    newItem: EstablecimientoModel
                ): Boolean {
                    return oldItem.hash == newItem.hash
                }

                override fun areContentsTheSame(
                    oldItem: EstablecimientoModel,
                    newItem: EstablecimientoModel
                ): Boolean {
                    return oldItem.nombre == newItem.nombre
                }
            }
    }

    private val mEstablecimientos: MutableList<EstablecimientoModel> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): EstablecimientosViewHolder {
        val binding = RowEstablecimientoBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
        )
        return EstablecimientosViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EstablecimientosViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val establecimiento = getItem(position)
        holder.bindItem(establecimiento!!)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mEstablecimientos.size
    }

    fun addMoreEstablecimientos(newEstablecimientos: List<EstablecimientoModel>) {
        mEstablecimientos.addAll(newEstablecimientos)
        submitList(mEstablecimientos)
    }

    class EstablecimientosViewHolder(val binding: RowEstablecimientoBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
            binding.root
        ) {
        fun bindItem(establecimiento: EstablecimientoModel) {
            binding.setVariable(BR.establecimiento, establecimiento)
        }
    }
}
```

**recycler_view.xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvEstablecimientos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_establecimiento" />
```

**Fragment.java**

```
val cvGoBackEstablecimientos = binding!!.cvGoBackEstablecimientos
val rvEstablecimientos = binding!!.rvEstablecimientos
val adapter = EstablecimientosAdapter()
rvEstablecimientos.setHasFixedSize(true)
rvEstablecimientos.adapter = adapter
cvGoBackEstablecimientos.setOnClickListener { requireActivity().onBackPressed() }
viewModel?.getNearFreeEstablecimientos(2.0, 2.0)
    ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { t -> adapter.addMoreEstablecimientos(t!!) }
```

Comment: Does adapter has valid layout manager?

Comment: I have in the xml the `app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"` attribute in the recyclerview, but I also tried to put the `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));`

Comment: Too much code, put only the relevant one. Where's submitList(...)? Where's ListAdapter class?

Comment: In the `addMoreEstablecimientos` method, in adapter.
I don't have the ListAdapter class, I have the ViewHolder in the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had some problems with the layout, I removed a CoordinatorLayout and it works now.